# Another Hessian determinant question

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

The Kulkarni–Nomizu product of two symmetric matrices $h_{ij}$ and $k_{kl}$ is
$$
(h\wedge \!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcirc k)_{ijkl} = h_{ik}k_{jl} + h_{jl}k_{ik} - h_{il}k_{jk} - h_{jk}k_{il}.
$$
'Squaring' a matrix with this product, we get
\begin{align}
(h\wedge \!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcirc h)_{ijkl} &= h_{ik}h_{jl} + h_{jl}h_{ik} - h_{il}h_{jk} - h_{jk}h_{il} \\
&= 2(h_{ik}h_{jl} - h_{il}h_{jk}),
\end{align}
(which I recognize as twice the determinant of $h_{ij}$ in 2D). In particular, if $h_{ij}$ is the Hessian of a scalar function $f$,
$$
h_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \equiv f_{,ij},
$$
then half the product is
$$
\tfrac{1}{2}(h\wedge \!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcirc h)_{ijkl} = f_{,ik}f_{,jl} - f_{,il}f_{,jk}.
$$
Again, in 2D, this is the determinant of the Hessian, which I understand to be the discriminant at a critical point (only in 2D).

Finally, if we trace this over the indices $(i,k)$, and again over $(j,l)$, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_j \tfrac{1}{2}(h\wedge \!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcirc h)_{ijij}
&= \sum_i h_{ii} \sum_j h_{jj} - \sum_i \sum_j h_{ij} h_{ji} \\
&= (h_{11}+h_{22}+\ldots)^2 - (h_{11}^2+h_{22}^2+\ldots+h_{12}h_{21}+\ldots) \\
&= 2(h_{11}h_{22}-h_{21}h_{21})+2(h_{11}h_{33}-h_{31}h_{31})+\ldots \\
&= 2\sum (\text{determinants of $2\times2$ minors of $h$.}) \\
&= 2\sum (\text{products of eigenvalues of $2\times2$ minors of $h$?})
\end{align}
If $h$ is the Hessian of $f$, this is
$$
2(f_{,11}f_{,22}-f_{,21}f_{,21})+2(f_{,11}f_{,33}-f_{,31}f_{,31})+\ldots 
$$
or (I think)
$$
2(\lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1\lambda_3 + \ldots + \lambda_2\lambda_3 + \ldots)
$$

---

#### Questions

1. What would possess me to take the Kulkarni–Nomizu product of a Hessian? Has anyone seen anything like this?
2. What does the product tell us about $f$ geometrically? (Not necessarily at a critical point).
3. What does the double trace tell us about $f$?
4. What does the sum of pairs of eigenvalues mean?? EDIT: I just found out this is called the 2nd symmetric function of eigenvalues. What does it mean?